# Restrict panning and rotation of PCL viewer, but allow only zooming

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am using the PCL library (PCLVisualizer class) to visualize the point cloud. I am able to see the point cloud. But I don't want it to move with the help of mouse / keyboard. I want a fix view which can only zoom (say top view). I want the smaller views to be fixed as shown in the image.
How can we fix the views. Not allow them to rotate or translate but only allowed to zoom. Any ideas.

Code for multiple viewers :

m_pViewer->createViewPort(0, 0, 1, 0.7, 0);

m_pViewer->createViewPort(0.0, 0.7, 0.33, 1, 1);

m_pViewer->createViewPort(0.33, 0.7, 0.66, 1, 2);

m_pViewer->createViewPort(0.66, 0.7, 1, 1, 3);

m_pViewer->addPointCloud(m_pCloud, m_pColorHandler, newCloudId, 0);
m_pViewer->addPointCloud(m_pCloud, m_pColorHandler, newCloudId.append("_left"), 1);
m_pViewer->addPointCloud(m_pCloud, m_pColorHandler, newCloudId.append("_middle"), 2);
m_pViewer->addPointCloud(m_pCloud, m_pColorHandler, newCloudId.append("_right"), 3);

[Multiple Views PCL viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJtWe.png)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? :)

Comment: @mortom123. Not yet.